# getActiveFilters not working on the cms page and working on the category page

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I am trying to get applied active filters on layered navigation. Below is my code which i had tried:-

```
<?php $r = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State(); ?>
<?php $_filters = $r->getActiveFilters(); ?>
<ul class="tool-result">
    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter):?>
        <li>
            <?php if ($_filter->hasData('children')): ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filter->getData('children') as $child): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $child['url'] ?>"><?php echo $child['label'] ?>&nbsp;<span>&times;</span></a>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_filter->getRemoveUrl() ?>" ?>><?php echo $_filter->getLabel() ?>&nbsp;<span>&times;</span></a>
            <?php endif ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

this code is working on the category page with layered navigation

and this code is not working on the cms page with the layered navigation

Comment: Could you tell us in which block/template you're trying to add this code? It would help with determining what would be the best solution. I'm guessing `$r` is returning either `null` or an empty object, because you're not in the right context.

Comment: my this code is in the header.phtml page

Answer (score 2):

`$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();`

and you get fetch like that

```
foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
    $item->getName(); // Name of the filter
    $item->getLabel(); // Currently selected value
    $item->getFilter()->getRequestVar(); // Filter code (usually attribute code, except category filter, where it equals "cat")
}
```

[reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119458/how-to-get-active-filters-attribute-code-in-state-phtml/119460#119460)