# How to get active filters attribute code in state.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been working on Magento C.E 1.9.0.2, and I am implementing custom AJAX product loader, I have achieved everything but I am not able to **filter out my product collection as per the selected filters**. All I need to have the attribute code of `selected filters`, which I think can be achieved from `state.phtml`, where we have the active filters. But, I am not able to get the correct method to to get the **active filter's attribute code and current selected values**. Need help....

Comment: If you just need attribute code if state.phtml this code may help you `$_filter->getAttributeModel()->getAttributeCode();`

Comment: I tried that already, didn't seem to work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
```

and you get fetch like that

```
foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
    $item->getName(); // Name of the filter
    $item->getLabel(); // Currently selected value
    $item->getFilter()->getRequestVar(); // Filter code (usually attribute code, except category filter, where it equals "cat")
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862967/magento-get-selected-filter-in-layered-navigation)

Comment: How can I get the selected values array in the same?

Comment: sorry don't get you ? what you want? are you want to create array of them?

Comment: No, I want the selected value of that filter like if I have selected brands for a brand filter.

Comment: `$item->getLabel();`  This will give you selected value.

Comment: Yes, it just did the job

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer above, you need a little more code to use this within the loop of `state.phtml`:

```
<?php
$_filters = $this->getActiveFilters();
$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
$attributeCodes = array();

// Loop to get all attribute codes indexed by attribute name
foreach ($appliedFilters as $item) {
    $attributeCodes[$item->getName()] = $item->getFilter()->getRequestVar();
}

// The rendering loop
foreach ($_filters as $_filter) {
    $attributeCode = $attributeCodes[$_filter->getName()];

    if ($attributeCode === 'some_thing') {
        // Something
    }
}
?>
```